# Padding next to divs, like cellspacing of table

Tags: html, css

I want to do the following:

http://s8.postimage.org/k82svi22r/example.gif

with only divs, css. Its ok to float left the cells, but Im stuck with spacings. I tried to use borders, but then divs next to each other became 2 lines. Or the color of title overleaps the border... I hope theres an easy way to do this!

Comment: This is easily possible. Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: I dont know what to show, just bunch of nested divs....

Comment: You should still show it. The point of SO is for us to help you with what you've tried, not for us to write an entire solution for you from scratch (although some people will).

Answer (score 5):

There is an easy way, a table. A calendar is a table of tabular data, so it's fine to use one!

Comment: I dont know. Everybody is saying tables is depricated.

Comment: not exactly OP actually its depends on our requirement where we need table so we should use like you used in calender as Andy is also saying calender is a table of tabular data so its fine......

Comment: Tables are not depreciated. The use of tables for laying out a website is bad practice and very outdated yes. But you aren't using it for laying out a site, you are using it for a table of data.

Comment: Tables aren't deprecated - they're very useful! It's just unwise to use them simply for display purposes. The fact that a calendar is tabular data is debatable, but I would say it's OK to use a table for this also.

Comment: Tables are definitely not deprecated. Tables for layout should not be used. But tables for data which was meant to be displayed on a table are perfectly acceptable, and even correct!

Answer (score 3):

Try this (this is a draft)

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #root{
        width:102px;
        overflow: auto;
        border-top : 1px solid black;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
      }
      .cell {
        width:50px;
        height: 50px;
        float:left;
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom:1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```